# Contradiction when differentiating?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $F = x+y$. Let $x = t$ and $y= \cos t$. By directly differentiating,

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = 1$$ and $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 1$$
Using the chain rule however,

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial {x}}\frac{dx}{dx} + \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial {y}}\frac{dy}{dx}$$ $$= 1-\sin x$$

How is this possible?

Comment: Why are you to trying to use the chain rule where it isn't required? And where does that $\;\sin x\;$ there come from?

Comment: @Timbuc I'm only using the chain rule to show the contradiction. The $sin x$ comes up from $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin x$ since $y = \cos x$

Comment: but then you're considering $\;y\;$ as a function of $\;x\;$ and thus what you called "direct diffentiation" is wrong. It should be $\;F_x=1+y_x'=1-\sin x\;$

Answer (score 1):

Your result from directly differentiating is incorrect.  $y$ is a function of $t$, which is equal to $x$.  So $y$ is a function of $x$.  Therefore, the derivative of $F=x+y$  with respect ot $x$ is the result from the chain rule.

In this case, you could write $F$ as $F=x + \cos(x)$, which may make things more clear.

Comment: Why is the result from directly differentiating incorrect? I held the other variable constant and then differentiated. Differentiating $x$ with respect to $x$ gives $1$ and differentiating a constant with respect to $x$ gives $0$.

Comment: You cannot hold constant something that depends on the variable with respect to which you're differentiating, @Vimzy

Comment: Let's consider two separate cases.  In case 1, F=x+y and there are no restrictions on x or y.  You could conceivably draw F.  For every (x,y) there is a point on some sort of surface.  How does this differ from the case you've presented?  In your case, x and y are related.  x=t, and y=cos(t).  So we don't have a surface for every (x,y).  Instead, we only have values for our function for those points that satisfy (t,cos(t)).  Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

$F(x,y)=x+y$ defines $F$ to be a function with domain $\mathbb{R}^2$ and range $\mathbb{R}$ that takes $(a,b)$ to $a+b$. With $F$ defined this way, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ is the derivative of $F$ with respect to the first coordinate (the one labeled $x$ in the definition), and it’s the function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that has constant value 1.

But as soon as you “let $x=t$ and $y=\cos t$,” the meaning of $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ becomes unclear. Is it a derivative of a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the first coordinate, or is it the derivative of the function of one variable $x$ that takes $x$ to $x+\cos x$?

It would be nice if standard mathematical notation were clearer about this, but it’s not.

Here’s [a nice essay](http://spin0r.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/the-difference-between-partial-and-total-derivatives/) on this topic.